# How can I run Kotlin function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, kotlin

I followed what Flutter did in https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels but it didn't work. I checked other people's work and still nothing. So what do you guys suggest?

```
class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this.getFlutterEngine()!!)
}


private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery"

override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
        call, result ->
        if (call.method == "MyMethod"){
            result.success("Hello Kotlin")
        }
    }
}}
```

and this is the method in flutter itself

```
static const platform = 
const MethodChannel("samples.flutter.dev/battery");


Future<void> MyMethod() async {
String value = "";

try{
  value = await platform.invokeMethod("MyMethod");
}
catch(e){
  print(e);
}
print(value);
}
```

Please, I've tried everything on internet but none of them worked. I beg your help for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my issue. It was in AndroidManifest.xml

it was

```
 android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity"
```

I changed it back to

```
   android:name=".MainActivity"
```